# 'SignupFormExtra' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: django, django-userena

That's my first time using userena in Django. i want to override signup form of userena and now have an error.

```
from userena import settings as userena_settings
from userena.models import UserenaSignup
from userena.utils import get_profile_model

class SignupFormExtra(SignupForm):
"""
A form to demonstrate how to add extra fields to the signup form, in this
case adding the first and last name.


"""
cellPhone = forms.CharField(label=_(u'CellPhone'),
                             max_length=30,
                             required=False)
first_name = forms.CharField(label=_(u'First name'),
                             max_length=30,
                             required=False)

last_name = forms.CharField(label=_(u'Last name'),
                            max_length=30,
                            required=False)

def save(self):
    """
    Override the save method to save the first and last name to the user
    field.

    """
    # First save the parent form and get the user.
    new_user = super(SignupFormExtra, self).save()

    # Get the profile, the `save` method above creates a profile for each
    # user because it calls the manager method `create_user`.
    # See: https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena/blob/master/userena/managers.py#L65
    new_user = get_profile_model()

    new_user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
    new_user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
    new_user.cellPhone = self.cleaned_data['cellPhone']
    new_user.save(self)

    # Userena expects to get the new user from this form, so return the new
    # user.
    return new_user
```

Actually i have class Profile in model.py and referred to userena like this:

```
class Profile(UserenaBaseProfile):
user = models.OneToOneField(User,
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                            unique=True,
                            verbose_name=_('user'),
                            related_name='my_profile')
```

can anyone help me to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need this part:

```
new_user = get_profile_model()
```

you get new_user from previous command, just save it and remove self from the new_user.save()

**new_user.save(self) -> new_user.save()**

```
def save(self):
    """
    Override the save method to save the first and last name to the user
    field.

    """
    # First save the parent form and get the user.
    new_user = super(SignupFormExtra, self).save()  
    new_user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
    new_user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
    new_user.cellPhone = self.cleaned_data['cellPhone']
    new_user.save()

    # Userena expects to get the new user from this form, so return the new
    # user.
    return new_user
```